# How to configure Nginx for serving Symfony2 app from location path?

Tags: symfony, nginx, subdirectory

No problem for me to setup a normal domain or vhost. But I don't get it right to serve from a different directory via location!

Wether the Symfony cookbook site nor the nginx symfony wiki page mention this scenario.

I walked throug several hints from Stackoverflow and elsewhere - but no success.

Is there any resource or working configuration someone can provide me?

Some information:

Symfony root web folder is not a sub folder of webroot; i need to setup a path like /admin for several domains directing to a separate Symfony folder:

Web Root for the domain (differs on domain):

```
/srv/http/domain.com/htdocs
```

Symfony web root for all domains accessible with /admin

```
/srv/http/shared/admin/web
```

Thanks in advance,

Micha